# remove duplicate from AutoCompleteStringCollection c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection treatmentCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    con.Open();
}
SqlCeCommand cmdTreatment = new SqlCeCommand("select Treatment from NewPatient", con);
SqlCeDataReader readerTreatment = cmdTreatment.ExecuteReader();
if (readerTreatment.Read() == true)
{
    while (readerTreatment.Read())
    {
        treatmentCollection.Add(readerTreatment["Treatment"].ToString());
    }
}
comboBox2.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
comboBox2.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
comboBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = treatmentCollection;
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    con.Close();
}
```

I want that the `combobox2` should have only different value.
and combobox gets value from `treatmentCollection` object of `AutoCompleteStringCollection` class
please help me?

Comment: Thank You Every One..i got the solution..

Comment: If you have the helpful answer - accept it. It will mark the question as closed.

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
select Treatment from NewPatient
```

to this:

```
select distinct Treatment from NewPatient
```

Comment: ohhh..yes....i forgot the sql query can do this...
thank you very much @Garath Sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only different values, you can use `DISTINCT` in your sql command like;

```
select DISTINCT Treatment from NewPatient
```

Check out [`Eliminating Duplicates with DISTINCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I use use this code and it is working fine.

```
string query = @"Select distinct [FieldName] from [tableName]";
```